# Этимология слова "бистро"

Tags: этимология

В "Толковом словаре русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" под ред. Н. Ю. Шведовой говорится:

> Бистр**о**, *нескл., ср.* Небольшая закусочная, маленький ресторан.
>   **•** Из франц. *bistro(t)*, восх. к русск. *быстро* (назв. возникло в конце Отечественной войны 1812 года, когда часть русских войск вошла на территорию Франции, — по-видимому, от возгласа "Быстро, быстро!", обращённого к французским рестораторам).

Несмотря на то, что на книга издана под эгидой РАН, такой вариант этимологии выглядит неправдоподобно, в связи с чем вопрос: есть ли другие версии происхождения этого слова?

Answer (score 1):

Да всё же есть в Вики.
Да, не авторитетный доказательный источник, но как источник версий - не хуже и не лучше других.

Главное, что она дает ссылку гна весьма солидное издание, где утверждается, что между войной 1812-1814 г. и первой фиксацией слова прошло много больше полувека.

> Происхождение названия Мемориальная доска на ресторане «À la Mère
>   Catherine», Париж.
>
> Популярная этимологическая версия связывает слово bistro с рус.
>   быстро; считается, что во время оккупации Парижа русские офицеры или
>   казаки требовали от французских официантов, чтобы те их обслуживали
>   побыстрее, и так и возникло название для заведения, где блюда
>   готовятся и подаются вскоре после заказа[1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE). Эта версия увековечена в
>   мемориальной доске на одном из ресторанов Монмартра.
>
> Данная версия не может рассматриваться в качестве достоверной, так как
>   первые упоминания использования слова «bistro» во французском языке
>   относятся лишь к 1880-м годам (по словарю Robert), когда никакого
>   заметного русского присутствия в Париже не было[2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistro). С другой стороны,
>   есть похожие диалектные и просторечные слова, означающие алкогольные
>   напитки, торговцев винами или владельцев кабачка, например,
>   bist(r)ouille, bistringue или bistroquet. Французский этимологический
>   словарь Robert связывает распространение этой группы слов с диалектным
>   (Север Франции) bistouille 'пойло, плохой алкоголь', отмеченным с 1845
>   года, а «русскую» версию происхождения слова данный французский
>   словарь квалифицирует как «чистую фантазию».

[Бистро | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE)

Ну и во французской вики - тож. 
[Bistro | fr.wikipedia.org](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistro)

Там даже интересное написание есть - «bistraud».

С французским у меня неважно, даю гуглоперевод нередактированный (чего никогда раньше не делал). Попрошу, если получиться, перевод у более сведующих

(хотел спойлер сделать - не получилось)

Происхождение слова Бистро является неопределенным и обсуждены:

Это может быть регионализм импортирован в Париже в девятнадцатом веке, откуда он будет распространен по всей Франции. Бистро может прийти Poitevin, "Bistraud" или "Mastroquet" - на севере Франции - или "bistroquet" - на юге - изначально это означает слуга и слуга торговца вином и торговец вином itself2. Это, как правило, чтобы укрепить это предположение о том, что слово "бистро" означало, в начале двадцатого века, "хранитель бистро", а также "учреждение, где они служат вино":

"На прилавке большой букет восторжествовала. Из-бистро фестиваля Martrodin. Подарок для детей! он сказал нам сам [...] Муж настаивал на том, что Бистро начинает читать суб-префектуры Луар и Шер для него он узнал и знал encore3. "

- Селин, Путешествие к концу ночи.

  Некоторые бистро рядом со словом "bistouille" сочетание кофе и алкоголя на севере Франции, который дал бы его имя учреждения, в котором служил, но мешает тот факт, что основной смысл делает не было создание, но тот, который servait2,4.
  Другие считают, что это происходит от слова сленга "Bistingo" (кабаре), что маловероятно, потому что опять же, первое историческое значение не было учреждение.
  Популярный этимологии (см табличку на фасаде Мать Екатерины Тертр на Монмартре) получает Бистро русский (кириллица: быстро), что означает "быстрый" и знакомства с русской оккупации, которая последовала за бой Париж 1814 российские солдаты не имеют право пить, и боясь быть удивлены приходом офицера, умоляли кафе, которые служат им кричали на русском языке: "БЫСТРО, БЫСТРО" "быстро, быстро." По словам Алана Рей, эту этимологию "должен быть отклонен по причинам хронологического, при отсутствии сертификатов слова в течение почти трех четвертей century.5. "Первая дата сертификации в 1884 году в следственных Воспоминания Рокет отца Жоржа Moreau.

Comment: А в каком году повесили доску, Вы не знаете? Кстати, фиксация слова в словарях обычно делается много позднее, чем слово появляется в речи.

Comment: Там даже не фиксация в словаре, а в словаре фиксируется, что это было в 1880-х. Про доску - не знаю.

Comment: Обычно в этимологических  словарях указывается: слово впервые зафиксировано  в таком-то источнике в таком-то году, в словарях - с такого-то года. Разница бывает лет в 50.

Comment: @Sibylla Мне трудно принять вашу трактовку. *"Первые упоминания использования слова «bistro» во французском языке относятся лишь к 1880-м годам (по словарю Robert),"* - тут не о слорваной фиксации идет речь, а том, что словарь ссылается на первую письменную фиксацию.

Answer (score 0):

Сами мы не местные, поэтому делимся [чем бог послал](http://montrealex.livejournal.com/103737.html):

> ...Нет ничего более далёкого от истины, чем «русское» происхождение
>   слова «Бистро». Критерий истины, как часто бывает в этих случаях,
>   словарь. Вот я давеча сгрузил «Малый Робер 2009 года» (2010 пока
>   недоступен, но будет скоро, уверен, а версию 2008 я даже сдуру купил,
>   когда учился, правда тогда мне всё оплачивали, даже книги).
>   Открывается со скоростью молнии и мы читаем в нём: bistrot ou bistro
>   [bistʀo] nom masculin ÉTYM. 1885.
>
> То есть первая неприятная для квасного патриота неожиданность -
>   слово появилось во французском в 1885 году, а в 1815 русских казаков
>   на Елисейских полях уже не стояло. То есть оно что, 70 лет ждало,
>   чтобы в язык впендюриться? Не, так не бувает в линхвистике! Неологизм
>   он потому и "новый логизм", что появляется сразу же в лексиконе.
>
> А как же «бувает»? Словарь объясняет: de l'argot bistingo « petit
>   restaurant » (1856), variante en bis- de bastringue, sur le modèle de
>   mastro(quet) « débit de boissons » (1859), что ***слово происходит от
>   арготизма «бистенго», что значит «ресторанчик», кое слово уже было
>   известно в 1856 году и являлось вариантом слова «бастренг»***, которое
>   образовалось по модели «мастро(ке)», то бишь «источник выпивки».
>
> Что ещё интереснее, так это то, что у меня четыре «Малых Робера» и
>   самый древний из них, естественно, бумажный, это издание 1981 года.
>   Так вот в нём вообще ничего не говорится про «русский след». В издание
>   1996 года, уже на сидюке, я лезть не стал, потому что пылится оно
>   где-то глубоко в шкафу, а вот диск 2008 посмотрел и обнаружил, что
>   издатели словаря делают попытку отмежеваться от русского происхождения
>   слова: 1882 bistrô; cette date écarte l'hypothèse d'une adaptation du
>   russe bystro « vite », qui n'aurait pu se faire qu'en 1814-1815 то
>   есть, если перевести, то мы имеем: эта дата опровергает гипотезу
>   русского происхождения слова, которое должно было бы появиться (во
>   французском языке) в 1814-15 годах. Издание 2009 года только повторит
>   это утверждение. Видимо, издателей задолбали уже с русской версией
>   происхождения этого слова.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить на заданный вопрос, надо определиться со следующим:

**Вопрос 1. А была ли закусочная** (в парижском районе Монмартр на площади Тертр, а именно «У матушки Катрин»)?  [Откуда пошла легенда, что слово "бистро" русского происхождения? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1332190-otkuda-poshla-legenda-chto-slovo-bistro-russkogo-proishozhdenija.html)

Вернее, была ли табличка с названием  этой закусочной, а еще вернее, когда она появилась: в 1814 году или много позже (в конце 19 века) в качестве удачной рекламы. **Это хотя бы можно узнать достоверно у французских историков?**

**Вопрос 2. Какова этимология слова "быстрый"?** Если не вдаваться в подробности, то быстрый — это скорее "бурный". Слово широко распространено в **славянских языках** (и.-е. корень bhu - раздуваться, надуваться, пухнуть, бушевать), а в скандинавских языках оно приобретает значение "ринуться, устремиться (норв. диалект  bustrig - стремительный). (Из словаря Черных).

А вот что там  с происхождением французских просторечных или диалектных слов bist(r)ouille, bistringue или bistroquet — хотелось бы узнать подробнее (у французских лингвистов).